# OIDC-client Cant log out. Error: no end session endpoint

Tags: angular, auth0, openid-connect

I am starting to implement a code flow with Auth0 as my identity provider.

The sign in works perfectly and I retrieve a valid token back from Auth0.

> The problem: I can't sign out.

Below is the error I am getting.

```
core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: no end session endpoint
Error: no end session endpoint
    at oidc-client.min.js:1
   ...
```

Here is my user manager config.

```js
const config = {
    authority: 'https://dev-hidden.eu.auth0.com',
    client_id: '--hidden--',
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/auth-callback`,
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile',
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    end_session_endpoint: 'https://dev-hidden.eu.auth0.com'
     ^^^ I dont think this does anything but I added it anyway
  };
```

I have tried the following to sign out, neither worked.

```js
this.userManager.signoutRedirect();
this.userManager.signoutRedirectCallback()
```

I'm not sure if its a client or an Auth0 issue.

I'm using `oidc-client 1.8.2` but have also tried other versions with the same result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Check https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/.well-known/openid-configuration to find `end_session_endpoint`.

Probably Auth0 doesn't support `end_session_endpoint`. I checked https://auth-dev.mozilla.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration and there is no `end_session_endpoint`. But they support `revocation_endpoint`, which may need different implementation on your end.

Maybe it will be better to use `auth0-spa-js` 
 for you; doc: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

Comment: So I guess as a further question. How does OIDC client support logging out with auth0?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (OpenID Connect + Google) `revokeAccessToken()` did the trick for me.